# After Soft keyboard popup, page content squeeze in to half the screen size in MAUI Blazor

Tags: android, blazor, maui

I am developing a android app using MAUI Blazor. I am using "vh" for most of the components' height. When I try to enter text in a text input field on an Android tablet, the soft keyboard pops up and all other content heights turn to half of the screen height. This makes the design look bad and not presentable. But i can't use "px" for component height, because i need to develop a responsive design for all size android tablets. can you suggest a solution for this?

can you suggest a solution for this?

Comment: You should provide a sample of code that you have a problem with at the very least - we can't guess what you have

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The keyboard in android works in one of 3 modes, which you can specify in your app's manifest

adjustNothing-  the screen doesn't change.  This mode is very rare and not recommended.

adjustPan-  the screen of your app is scrolled such that the cursor is assured to be on screen.  This is frequently used on screens showing long scrollable content

adjustResize-  your app is resized to fit the space above the keyboard.  This may cause visual items to change size. This is frequently used on screens with sparse content with lots of empty space (login screens are a great example)

It sounds like your app is using resize.  Change it to pan if you want the other behavior.

Comment: Yes you are right. I'm using adjustResize. But I try to use adjustPan. It's not working as expected. look like it is a bug of MAUI7 version. [link](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/11274)
I think they will fix it in .NET 8. But i can't wait that long. I am just trying to find a alternative solution.